# Get the 1st instance of a property using reduce and Object.values

Tags: javascript, object

I'm reducing this forecast to get a single result returned for each date.

My getForecastForDay function works except it selects the last instance of each date. This is only problematic because the last instance in each date set has the same temp_min and temp_max.

So I need to grab the first instance of each date instead of the last. I tried but I don't get it. How do I pick the first instance of each date from reduce?

Note: This is a modified version of my forecast results. The time on the date property and some other properties has already been removed in this example.

```
const forecast = [
{date: "2018-05-24", temp_min: 49.87, temp_max: 57.1},
{date: "2018-05-24", temp_min: 49.08, temp_max: 53.9},
{date: "2018-05-24", temp_min: 54.52, temp_max: 56.93},
{date: "2018-05-24", temp_min: 61.8, temp_max: 61.8},
{date: "2018-05-24", temp_min: 66.58, temp_max: 66.58},
{date: "2018-05-25", temp_min: 68.64, temp_max: 68.64},
{date: "2018-05-25", temp_min: 66.33, temp_max: 66.33},
{date: "2018-05-25", temp_min: 62.41, temp_max: 62.41},
{date: "2018-05-25", temp_min: 58.97, temp_max: 58.97},
{date: "2018-05-25", temp_min: 55.15, temp_max: 55.15},
{date: "2018-05-25", temp_min: 56.24, temp_max: 56.24},
{date: "2018-05-25", temp_min: 59.29, temp_max: 59.29},
{date: "2018-05-25", temp_min: 65.89, temp_max: 65.89},
{date: "2018-05-26", temp_min: 67.96, temp_max: 67.96},
{date: "2018-05-26", temp_min: 65.05, temp_max: 65.05},
{date: "2018-05-26", temp_min: 59.42, temp_max: 59.42},
{date: "2018-05-26", temp_min: 55.52, temp_max: 55.52},
{date: "2018-05-26", temp_min: 52.17, temp_max: 52.17},
{date: "2018-05-26", temp_min: 53.06, temp_max: 53.06},
{date: "2018-05-26", temp_min: 58.72, temp_max: 58.72},
{date: "2018-05-26", temp_min: 63.51, temp_max: 63.51}
];

const getForecastForDay = 
Object.values(resultsDateMod.reduce((acc,cur)=> Object.assign(acc,{
[cur.date]:cur} ),{}))

const threeDayForecast = getforecastForDay.slice(0,3);
threeDayForecast
```

I have a the code in a repl here: 
https://repl.it/@portabletomb/FittingRoyalblueParameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if the accumulator has the `cur.date` property first, and only `assign` if the date is lacking - that way, you skip duplicates, rather than duplicates overwriting the originals.

```js
const forecast=[{date:"2018-05-24",temp_min:49.87,temp_max:57.1},{date:"2018-05-24",temp_min:49.08,temp_max:53.9},{date:"2018-05-24",temp_min:54.52,temp_max:56.93},{date:"2018-05-24",temp_min:61.8,temp_max:61.8},{date:"2018-05-24",temp_min:66.58,temp_max:66.58},{date:"2018-05-25",temp_min:68.64,temp_max:68.64},{date:"2018-05-25",temp_min:66.33,temp_max:66.33},{date:"2018-05-25",temp_min:62.41,temp_max:62.41},{date:"2018-05-25",temp_min:58.97,temp_max:58.97},{date:"2018-05-25",temp_min:55.15,temp_max:55.15},{date:"2018-05-25",temp_min:56.24,temp_max:56.24},{date:"2018-05-25",temp_min:59.29,temp_max:59.29},{date:"2018-05-25",temp_min:65.89,temp_max:65.89},{date:"2018-05-26",temp_min:67.96,temp_max:67.96},{date:"2018-05-26",temp_min:65.05,temp_max:65.05},{date:"2018-05-26",temp_min:59.42,temp_max:59.42},{date:"2018-05-26",temp_min:55.52,temp_max:55.52},{date:"2018-05-26",temp_min:52.17,temp_max:52.17},{date:"2018-05-26",temp_min:53.06,temp_max:53.06},{date:"2018-05-26",temp_min:58.72,temp_max:58.72},{date:"2018-05-26",temp_min:63.51,temp_max:63.51}];
const getForecastForDay = 
  Object.values(forecast.reduce((acc,cur)=> (
    acc[cur.date]
    ? acc
    : { ...acc, [cur.date]: cur }
  ), {}));
const threeDayForecast = getForecastForDay.slice(0,3);
console.log(threeDayForecast);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I was trying to compare them but I was doing it the totally wrong way.

Comment: Would arguably be more efficient to just add the property rather than reassign a new object each time.

Comment: Hmmm, So I just updated my repl with your code. This seems to only change the date property in the first date result. The rest are still pulling the last instance in the forecast

Comment: @TYPOI Works perfectly for me - just press "Run code snippet" in my post to see for yourself

Comment: @CertainPerformance Apologies, you're totally right. It's the stupid API returning the same number for both temp min and temp max that confused me. I'll investigate that

Answer (score 1):

Before adding the next object, check if the date already exists in the results:

```
forecast.reduce((results, next) => {
    if (!results[next.date]) {
        results[next.date] = next;
    }
    return results;
}, {});
```

"Minified":

```
forecast.reduce((res, next) => res[next.date] ? res : (res[next.date] = next, res), {});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is ordered then all you need to do is ignore any further records with the same date i.e.

```
const getForecastForDay = Object.values(
  forecast.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (!acc[cur.date]) {
      acc[cur.date] = cur;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
)
```